# How to let the dropdown of jQuery autocomplete exceed the browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, window, drop-down-menu, jquery-autocomplete

Does anybody know if it is possible to let the dropdown menu of the jQuery autocomplete exceed the browser window?

This is possible for the common html select menu (Internet Explorer):

```
<html><body>
<script>window.resizeTo(300, 200);</script>
<form><select>
    <option>Some option 01</option>
    <option>Some option 02</option>
    <option>Some option 03</option>
    <option>Some option 04</option>
    <option>Some option 05</option>
    <option>Some option 06</option>
    <option>Some option 07</option>
    <option>Some option 08</option>
    <option>Some option 09</option>
</select></form>
</body></html>
```

Can this also be achieved using javascript/jQuery or will the results always be rendered within the browser window?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autocomplete plugin, even though it looks like a popup menu, is still html markup and is rendered **within** the browser's window, like any other element of a webpage.

What you can do is set a `max-height` on the menu.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

This will add a vertical scrollbar if the height exceeds 100px.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I have the requirement to let a dropdown menu exceed the browser window. Any idea how to maybe abuse a standard select form to act as a jQuery autocomplete result container?

Comment: Well, there is this jquery plugin - [uniform](http://uniformjs.com/) - which allows styling native form elements but still being able to use them. It's achieved s by setting the opacity to zero so the native element is not visible but still receive events and such. You could use a similar way of working. Good luck making that happens with the combobox plugin though ;-)